# How to place all classes under one generic class type?

Tags: java, class, generics, subclass

I have n number of java classes each containing its own set of variables.
I have a method which has to accept one of these n classes as a parameter based on some condition. 
How can I make all these classes as subclasses to a generic type so that my method signature accepts all these different types? I dont want to overload the method. And if use the type 'Object' for the parameter, I am losing the nature of the input param class I am passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
public interface common<T extends common<?>> {
    public void commonMethod(T param, ...);
}

public class child implements common<child> {
    public void commonMethod(child param, ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will try this

Answer (score 3):

Define an interface that all your classes implement. Then declare your parameter in the method's head as the type of that interface.

Comment: I tried this approach. But I had to explicitly type cast the object inside the method to regain its behavior.

Comment: No you don't need to cast if the interface defines all methods you need. Also all your classes should have something in common (hence the interface), otherwise your design is probably wrong or you should consider overloading.

Comment: So what do you want? Are you looking for "how to write a method which accepts a generic type and without casting it can accept all of methods of all of child classes?" :-?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make all these classes as subclasses to a generic type so that my method signature accepts all these different types?

Simple make an abstract class, `MySuperClass`, this class gets inherited by all the classes you wanted to be passed to the Method. This super class have common functionality and attributes.

The other way, if your subclasses are likely to extend other class; or, there is nothing common among the class (except the fact that they all are passed to the method of yours) you can have an interface, say `MySuperClass` (well ideally, I like interface to start with I, like `IMySuperClass`).

> I dont want to overload the method.

Once you have your super-class, or interface ready, your method signature would look something like `myMethod(Param1 val1, MySuperClass myObj, Param3 val3)`.

Simple.

Comment: Same as implementing an interface. I had to explicitly type cast inside the method.

Comment: If there is no common functionality I suggest to overload the method. If there are common functionality, then abstracting things and passing to same method makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use polymorphism (as suggested by the others), then you could use Java generics to do this:

E.g. this can be used to put any object into a cache:

```
public <T> void doSomethingWithObject(final T object) {
    ...
}
```

And you could call it like this: e.g. using String

```
yourInstance.<String> doSomethingWithObject(object);
```